# Is the excel autofilter 'equals' not a subset of 'contains'?

Tags: excel, autofilter

I wanted to filter on a customer number in an excel sheet with the autofilter and to ensure to ignore any trailing spaces I used the 'contains' filter. However I got no result. The number was present in the data, it was within the filter range, and I was able to filter on it with 'equals'.

How is that possible? Shouldn't 'contains' find all values that are 'equal' anyways?

To be fair: I have to work on an old set of software with Excel 2003.

Comment: Can you share a subset of your data along with the filter condition? makes it easy to understand

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot. The reason for the old software I am working on is that the data is confidential and the system is separated from the internet. The customer number was a ten digit number like 1234567890.

Comment: If the customer number is really a number, not a string, then `contains` won't work since it only works with strings.

Comment: Try changing the column format to 'General'..

Comment: If this is the case then this might be an explanation. It would be logic that 'equals' on the other hand allows numeric comparison. However I did change the format to general. Maybe something went wrong here.

Comment: Changing the number format to `General` will not help. Select the column, call Data-Text to Columns, in Step 3 of the wizard select Data Format Text. Now the `contains` filter should work.